# Passportjs PREVENT auto-login after signing up

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

Using passportjs for authentication. When a user signs up, I want a message to appear letting them know they can now sign in with their account. As of right now, signing up also logs them in which throws my notifications off:

- "You may now sign up"
- "You are already logged in"

and

- "welcome new user"

How can I prevent this? I tried `req.logout()` by the end of `verifySignup()` was reached and no dice.

My router:

```
  router.route('/login')
  .get(function(req, res){
    // If the user is already logged in, redirect them to the dashboard
    if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
      req.flash('alert', 'You are already logged in');
      res.redirect('/');
    } else {
      // Otherwise, allow them to login
      // Redirect them to the login pages
      res.render('login',
      { host: req.baseUrl,
        error: req.flash('error'),
        success: req.flash('success'),
        alert: req.flash('alert')
      });
    }
  }).post(passport.authenticate('local-login', {
        successRedirect: '/',
        failureRedirect: '/login',
        badRequestMessage: "You need to enter your username and password",
        failureFlash: true // allow flash
      })
  );

  router.route('/signup')
    .get(function(req, res){
      // If the user is already logged in, redirect them to the dashboard
      if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
        req.flash('alert', 'You must first log out before signing up for a new account');
        res.redirect('/');
      } else {
        // Otherwise, allow them to signup
        // Redirect them to the signup pages
        res.render('signup',
        { host: req.baseUrl,
          error: req.flash('error'),
          success: req.flash('success'),
          alert: req.flash('alert')
        });
      }
    }).post(passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
          successRedirect: '/login',
          failureRedirect: '/signup',
          badRequestMessage: "You must fill in all of the form fields.",
          failureFlash: true // allow flash
        })
    );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Two ways you can prevent auto-login:**

**1.** Provide an [optional callback](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/master/lib/middleware/authenticate.js#L24) in passport.authenticate. Example...

```
      router.post('/signup', function(req, res, next) {

        /* ... */

        passport.authenticate('local-signup', function(err, user, info) {
          if (err) { return next(err) }
          if (!user) { return res.redirect('/signup') }
          res.redirect('/login');
        })(req, res, next);
      });
```

*Note:* that if a callback is supplied, it becomes the application's
 responsibility to log-in the user, establish a session, and otherwise perform the desired operations.

With this example, login nor session storing occurs. Therefore auto-login is prevented.

**2.** The easier solution. Use option `session: false` to disable using the session.

```
.post(passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
              successRedirect: '/login',
              failureRedirect: '/signup',
              badRequestMessage: "You must fill in all of the form fields.",
              failureFlash: true, // allow flash,
              session: false // prevent auto-login
            })
```

With this solution, no user info is stored in the session instance and so redirect to `/login` notifies "You may now log in with your account" correctly.